# Integration by parts of logarithmic derivative

Tags: integration

I have a simple question that seems to have me stumped, so some help would be greatly appreciated.

Consider the function $g(x)=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}  $ where the prime denotes the derivative with respect to $x$.   What I am interested in calculating is actually it's integral: $I = \int g(x) \,  dx$. Now I know $g(x)$ is the logarithmic  derivative: $g(x) = \frac{d} {dx}\left[ \ln( f(x) ) \right] $, so I know that $I=\ln( f(x) )$. But if I integrate by parts,  I get:

$I=\frac{1}{f(x)}\cdot f(x) - \int f(x) \cdot \left(-\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)^2}\right) dx = 1 + \int  \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} dx = 1 + I.   $

This seems to be a complete contradiction, (0=1 - oh dear!) so I know I have gone wrong somewhere.  Please help!

Comment: Use sobstitution $u=f(x)$.

Comment: You're forgetting the constant of integration

Comment: The "contradiction" comes from leaving out the arbitrary constants in your integration. Include that and the contradiction disappears.

Comment: You have 1+ln(f)+K. 1+K is still a constant. Saying either ln(f)+C or ln(f)+K+1 is the same.

Comment: You have forgotten the arbitrary integration constant. The two primitives differ by a constaht. The actual integral would be $I+C$: forgetting the arbitrary constant is a common mistake.

Comment: But surely that constant isn't arbitrary? It has to be equal to -1 or there's still a problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Direct Integration**
$$ \int \frac{1}{f(x)}\frac{d}{dx}[f(x)]\ dx$$
$$= \int \frac{1}{f(x)}\ df(x)= \ln f(x)+C$$
**Integration by parts**
$$ u= \frac{1}{f(x)}$$
$$du=-\frac{1}{f(x)^2}\frac{d}{dx}f(x)\ dx= -\frac{1}{f(x)^2}\ df(x) $$
$$dv = \frac{d}{dx}[f(x)]\ dx= df(x)$$
$$v=\int df(x)=f(x)$$
So now we have
$$\frac{f(x)}{f(x)}+\int \frac{f(x)}{f(x)^2}\ df(x)$$
$$=1+\int \frac{1}{f(x)}\ df(x)$$
$$=\ln f(x)+1+C$$
$$=\ln f(x)+C$$

Comment: I know it's not necessary,  as I stated. But I couldn't see how to do it if I did do it by parts

Comment: @Stumped101, please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update,  I think I need to do a bit more reading as I think I don't always include everything you do when I integrate by parts. I have learned it simply by rote (one times the integral of two minus the integral of what you just integrated times the differential of the first), whereas your answer seems more correct especially regarding keeping all the infinitesimals. Thanks!

Comment: @Stumped101, your welcome. We usually thank each other by upvoting and/or accepting answers.

Comment: @Stumped101, I personally stay far away from Lagrange's notation for the derivative.